# How to get back the two components of a long integer

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-shift

```
 DWORDLONG index = ((((DWORDLONG) i.nFileIndexHigh) << 32) | i.nFileIndexLow);
```

Given index, I want to find out what the components of i.fileindexhigh and i.fileindexlow are. Is it possible? A general idea would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, its possible, you just need to do the inverse operation of what you posted: instead of `<<` and `|`, `>>` and `&`,

```
nFileIndexLow = index & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;
nFileIndexHigh = index >> 32;
```

Consider researching on bitwise operations, or at least put your calculator in hexadecimal/binary mode and play with masks and shifts.

Comment: I'd like to note that while for this scenario it works, not all uses of `<<` and `|` can be reversed. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

i.nFileIndexHigh == index >> 32;
i.nFileIndexLow == index & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;